# OpenGL program shows only what is behind the screen

Tags: c++, opengl

When I run my OpenGL program, if there is currently a text editor open, the opengl program shows that portion in its screen. Or a web browser is open, opengl program shows that part of the browser. Here is my main function :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);  
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH ); 
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Program");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

my display function :

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(posz,posy,posz, 0, 0, 0, upx, upy, upz);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,-0.25f,0.0f);
      glVertex3f(-0.5f,-0.25f,0.0f);
      glVertex3f(-0.75f,0.25f,0.0f);

    glEnd();
}
```

It doesn't give any error or warning, it just displays what is already on the screen. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Check if some of your initializations have reported errors (e.g. some unsupported display formats etc), that's the most common reason for me for such behavior.

Comment: Same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577474/why-is-my-opengl-code-not-working from just a few days ago.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I searched for the problem, but I couldn't find the solution. The title in that problem is not very explanatory.

Comment: Absolutely, I am surprised that question was not down-voted for its title alone. Questions about _"why is ... not working"_ with code and no explanation are frowned upon, but useless titles like that should be even more so.

Comment: Yes, for these types of problems it's not easy to identify duplicates until you know the answer. It comes up very commonly, though. I have an article on my personal web site that covers the most common reasons for problem of this kind, and this one is listed close to the bottom, under "Frame Is Not Displayed": http://retokoradi.com/2014/04/21/opengl-why-is-your-code-producing-a-black-window/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glutInitDisplayMode (... GLUT_DOUBLE)` tells the window system to use double-buffered rendering, but you have no swap buffer calls anywhere in your code.

Basically, you always draw into the back-buffer when this happens and the window system only paints its windows using the contents of the front-buffer. The idea there is that the front-buffer is always a finished image and it works great when you actually swap buffers after you finish drawing your frame. But as it stands right now, your front-buffer is always undefined.

To fix this, add a call to `glutSwapBuffers ()` at the end of `void display ()`. That will copy/exchange your back-buffer and the front-buffer so your rendered output is visible.